# Two different data types in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Currently I am programming an application using Entity Framework and LINQ. Below I have created a method `CarsRow` which assigns different results to properties. Then a list is filled using a `foreach` loop.

Everything currently only works with one parameter (in this case is `Cars`).

The problem: How can I include a second parameter(data type) and then fill the list `carList` with it. For example, the `Colors` class. At the end an Excel table should be created containing data from different EF classes.

```
private void Main()
{
    var rows = new List<ObjectContactsRow>();

    List<Cars> carList = new List<Cars>();

    carList = _ctx.Objekte.OrderBy(p => p.Nummer).ToList();

    //how can i integrate the data of class Colors in the loop together with the class Cars   

    foreach (var cars in carList)
    {
        var line = rows.Any() ? rows.Max(p => p.LineNumber) + 1 : 2;
        var newrow = CreateNewRow(cars, "parameter of type Colors", line);
        rows.Add(newrow);
    }

    CreateExcelFile(rows);
}

private CarsRow CreateNewRow(Cars obj, Colors col, int line)
{
    var objCars = obj.Cars;
    var colColor = col.Colors;

    return new CarsRow(line)
    {
        Cars = objCars,
        Colors = colColor,
    };
}
```

Comment: your problem is not clear at all. what do you mean by a second parameter? where does that belong?

Comment: Where are you getting the "data of class Color"? Just add an inner (or outer) loop going over that data.

Comment: Hi – Siavash Rostami it's about the parameter "col". It should also be in the foreach loop, but it has different type, namely Colors

Comment: Hello  Heretic Monkey the data come from the Colors class, which was created using Entity Frameworks. The idea with the loops is good I think. Do you know some good examples in Stackoverflow? Thanks

Comment: i still don't understand where the color comes from? i assume colors should have a linking field with cars. in that case you should be able to join them and retrieve the cars's color. you cannot just add two totally unrelated entities in one bowl

Comment: Hello  Siavash Rostami  that's not a problem. Yes you have quite theoretically that is also possible. But the columns in Linq can also be taken individually and not as in SQL. My problem is how to run two different data types in one loop. Maybe really as an inner or outer loop. I don't know yet

Comment: I have changed now the title. I hope now is better to understand

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want [the Cartesian Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of all `Car`s with all `Color`s as a `ValueTuple<Car,Color>`.

To do a Cartesian Product of any two lists `Foo` and `Bar` in Linq do this:

```
// (This approach uses the extension method syntax instead of the C# keywords `from`, `join`, etc)
// Type names have been added to lambda functions to make it obvious what the values are.

IEnumerable<Foo> fooValues = ...
IEnumerable<Bar> barValues = ...

IEnumerable< ( Foo, Bar ) > cartesianProduct = fooValues
    .SelectMany( Foo foo => barValues, ( Foo foo, Bar bar ) => /* the following syntax creates a new ValueTuple in C# 7: */ ( foo, bar ) );

// or more succinctly (removing unnecessary type names):
var cartesianProduct = fooValues
    .SelectMany( foo => barValues, ( foo, bar ) => ( foo, bar ) );
```

In your case:

```
List<Car> cars = _ctx.Objekte
    .OrderBy( c => c.Nummer )
    .ToList();

List<Color> colors = // (you haven't shown how you get a List<Color>)

IEnumerable<(Car,Color)> cartesianProduct = cars
    .SelectMany( c => colors, ( car, color ) => ( car, color ) );
```

You can then iterate over `cartesianProduct` directly - but I don't think you need to because your `CarsRow` object is identical to the `(Car,Color)` `ValueTuple` object, but if you want to do additional processing then you can do this:

```
foreach( (Car car, Color color) in cartesianProduct )
{
    // do stuff with `car` and `color`
}
```